# How would you use recursion to find the result of more than two arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

For instance if I want to find the result of xy-z recursively for any number of x,y and z, for x amount of time. So lets say that x=5, y=6 and z=7, when i= 1 the result would be 1(6)-7 and on the second call i would be 2 so that would be 2(6)-7 this would continue until we reach 5( the value of x). I know how to do this iteratively and it works.

```
    def formul(x,y,z):
        result=0
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            result+= i*y-z
        return result
```

I have this so far for recursive that doesn't work:

```
    def underattack1(n,x,y):
        if n==0:
            return 0
        else:
            return n*x-y-underattack1(n-1,x,y)
```

I was thinking of adding another argument for result but not sure how to approach it. If i use 3,3,4 with the iterative method i get 6 which i expect, but if i use the same values recursively I get 2. Please help.

Comment: What "result" are you trying to find? What is wrong with your current code (what do you expect, and what are you getting instead)? Your current question is much to vague on all of these questions, so there's no possible way anyone can answer it.

Comment: Show us some code that calls `underattack1()` with a specific bunch of parameters, what output you get back, and what output you expect. So far you have only told us that you call it with some parameters (that you don't specify) and that you don't like what you get back.

Comment: I edited to hopefully be more precise now

Comment: Your recursive version gives the same answer as the iterative one if you change `n*x-y - underattack1(n-1,x,y)` to `n*x-y + underattack1(n-1,x,y)`, i.e., change the subtraction to addition to agree with your iterative version.  In other words, there's nothing magical about having multiple arguments for regression, your bug was a simple typo.  Note also that there's no reason to change the names in your argument list.  `n`, `x`, and `y` work equally well if you map them back to `x`, `y`, and `z` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In your iterative function, you're adding the result. But in your recursive function you're subtracting it. That's the problem with your recursive function.

```
>>> def underattack1(x, y, z):
        return 0 if x == 0 else x*y-z + underattack1(x-1, y, z)

>>> underattack1(3, 3, 4)
6
```